# Last element of a struct array - C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm a bit confused about a thing :

If I have an array of structs: `table` whith a length of `X` and I want to access the last element of it: `table[X]` or `table[X-1]`. If it's `table[X-1]`, what `table[X]` contains ?

Comment: The last element is `table[x - 1]`, `table[x]` is out of the bounds and can contain anything.

Comment: Then why table[X] even exists if it contains anything ?

Comment: What do you mean with _table[X] even exists_? `table[x + 1000]` also exists (contains data or garbage) but you are not allowed to access it because is out of the limits of the array.

Comment: `table[X]` is equivalent to access to the case at `table + X`. So if the adress is in your acceptable memory, it will work.

Comment: @KeineLust I mean why is table[x] a part of the array if it does not contain something 'usual' or something that makes sense?

Comment: @OthmaneAllamou, `table[x]` is not part of the array, arrays are base 0 in C, so the range is `[0 ... n-1]`

Comment: @PaulAnkman It is undefined behavior. It cannot "work"; since there is no way to figure out (within the bounds of the C programming language) what is should do.

Comment: @OthmaneAllamou : there is no "out of bounds" exception like you might be accustomed to in other languages. You as the programmer need to ensure not to go beyond the bounds of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indexing of array in C starts with zero, i.e. the first element will be in `table[0]`, the second in `table[1]`, the third in `table[2]` ... and the last on in `table[X-1]`.

`table[X]` is outside of the arrays bounds. C does not have bounds checking, so compiler allows accessing it, but this is an undefined behaviour, i.e. you will never know what happens. Reading it can give back memory garbage or can lead to an OS exception like segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Structs work in memory the same way that an integer or some other basic data type would in this instances. Your array would just be separated by sizeof(struct) instead of sizeof(the basic data type).

It'd still start at 0, and end at X - 1. The type of arrays usually just really defined 2 things:

The amount of bytes per index, and how to treat the data.

Picture an array of size 3 with structs that contain 5 bytes of data. Your array would just be set as follows:

```
-----|-----|-----|????|
s1   |s2   |s3   |????|
```

Just because it exists, doesn't mean our program knows what it is. the 4th [3] index (????) would be an index out of bounds of our array. It is possible however you could get some meaningful value here, but very unlikely. Most of the time it will either be garbage, or cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the same for any kind of array. If you have one with the size 
`X` :

```
int a[5];
struct my_struct ms[10];
...
```

you specify the amount of elements in that array. Because the 1st element is element 0, the last element is always `X - 1`.

If you try to access the element `a[X]` you will get [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C use zero indexing, meaning they start with `0` and end with `n-1`. Not to be confused with array declarations, where you write the size expressed in number of items. The syntax for accessing an array and declaring one looks similar, which is why this can be confusing for beginners.

Example:

```
int main (void)
{
  int array[5]; // allocate an array with 5 elements
  array[0] = 0; // access first element
  array[4] = 0; // access last element (index 4)

  array[5] = 0; // BAD, accessing the array out of bounds: index 5 gives item number 6
}
```

And this is why the canonical way to write for loops in C is this:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
```

where `n` is the size of the array, and the iterator `i` will have the values from `0` to `n-1`.